# python string encrypt/decrypt errors

Tags: python, encryption

I was following this link [link](http://sentdex.com/sentiment-analysisbig-data-and-python-tutorials-algorithmic-trading/encryption-and-decryption-in-python-code-example-with-explanation/) and it is working with what I presume is an error. This is the output I get when decrypting an encrypted string. I can't copy it so this is the image:

[image]

It should decrypt to `mYs3cr3t!` string.

Edit, here is my code:

```
def encrypt(self,param):
        BLOCK_SIZE = 16

        PADDING = '{'

        pad = lambda s: s + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(s) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING

        EncodeAES = lambda c, s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
        secret = "mynotsosecretkey"
        print 'encryption key:',secret
        cipher = AES.new(secret)

        encoded = EncodeAES(cipher, param)
        print 'Encrypted string:', encoded

        return (encoded,secret)

    def decryption(self,passwd):
        PADDING = '{'
        DecodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).rstrip(PADDING)

        encryption,key = self.encrypt(passwd)

        cipher = AES.new(key)
        decoded = DecodeAES(cipher, encryption)
        print decoded
```

As for the output, I am unable to copy it because it contains some weird characters.

Comment: Please post the relevant code *here*. If you run the example in the interpreter (e.g. IDLE) you will be able to copy the outputs, too.

Comment: What you are seeing is what is supposed to be the plaintext. Please print a python representation of the data instead of the string itself by writing `print "Decrypted, without padding: "+repr(decoded)` instead. Also, please add such a line for all intermediate values: in `encrypt`: `print "param: "+repr(param)`, `print "padded param: "+repr(pad(param))`; in `decryption`: `print "ciphertext: "+repr(cipher.decrypt(passwd))`.